# JDBC .net connection possible

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

Is it possible to use a JDBC connection in a VB.net application? I am unable to find any example code in order to connect to an Oracle Database using JDBC within .net without the need to use Oracles .net drivers (they seem to not work without the Oracle client being installed and thats a licence problem)

So any help would be great! :o)

David

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "license problem"?

Comment: JDBC is for a java library and you cannot use it in .net.

Comment: As in for each client that will need to run my .net application, they will need to install the oracle client for the .net oracle drivers to work (authorize, etc) and each machine will need its septate licences to install that which means $$$.

Comment: I believe the license provides a distribution clause.

Comment: As well as the instant client, there is a free Oracle XE client. No $$$ issue there. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) instead of the "full" Oracle client? That's free, so shouldn't give you any licensing problems.

Comment: Still needs the client to be installed in order to work. Thats what i've been trying to use and those who already have the client software installed works but those who do not, it doesn't.

Comment: @StealthRT: Then you're not doing it properly, by the sounds of it. I would work on getting Oracle Instant Client to work rather than going a different route. "Installation" should just be a matter of unzipping and either changing the path or putting your executables in the same directory.

Comment: **Install.bat odp.net2 c:\oracleOwn DevSuiteHome1** is what i ran in order to install the instant client.

Comment: @StealthRT: Not sure, to be honest. But I'd be surprised if it simply didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [System.Data.OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient%28VS.90%29.aspx) from MS?

Comment: Yes, same type of thing. It needs the oracle client to be installed.